# Off canvas menu appear on scroll

Tags: scrolltop

I've tried a lot of different things I've seen online (tutorials and videos) but I can't seem to get this to work.

What I have is a hero banner at the top with 100% width and height. The menu has been hidden up using -webkit-transform: translate(0,-100%); and once the user scrolls down to the bottom of the hero banner, the menu will then appear, sliding down using -webkit-transform: translate(0,0); within an addClass. I have used ease to animate it. However, my javascript isn't working.

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Fy3q/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var nav = $(".slide-nav-container");
var banner = $(".hero");

$(window).scroll(function() {

    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (windowpos >= banner.outerHeight()) {
        nav.addClass("slide-menu");
    } else {
        nav.removeClass("slide-menu");
    }

});
```

});

Comment: First of all, your fiddle doesn't work because you didn't add the 'jquery' library. I added it and it works. Did you add jquery to your website? <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Hi newboyhun, sorry forgot to add the jquery. And yeh, it works on the jsfiddle, but in my site it doesn't. Yes, I added jquery library in the site. What could be preventing it from working on my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only checking for the height of the banner, you need to add it to the position too.

```
windowpos >= banner.outerHeight()+banner.offset().top
```

`banner.offset().top` will return you the position of the banner on your site, adding its height will be the bottom of the banner.

Comment: This still doesn't work on my site. It does the exact same thing on the fiddle though.

Comment: Hi newboyhun, I think I figured out why it doesn't work. Inside the body, I have a primary-container that contains all content except for a side off canvas menu that I have for smaller media queries. When I took this off, the code worked. Do you know how to modify the javascript so that it looks inside the primary-container instead of the body?

Comment: Ok I've figured it out now. I put my webpage's content inside a primary-container so the javascript, since it was using the $(window) commands, it couldn't find the elements inside the body. I just changed the $(window) to $("primary-container"). Thanks for the attempt newboyhun. Will check you anyway.